# Windows 10 improved my GPU

Tags: drivers, windows-10, graphics-card, windows-update, display-driver

From what I saw number of drivers provided by Windows Update vastly improved. My question is why?

More interesting fact is that my 6 years old Ati Radeon HD 4770 has new drivers provided by Windows Update. Who did this? The latest version provided by Ati/AMD is for XP and is more than one year old. Who wrote new drivers? Microsoft? AMD? Was AMD forced by Microsoft to do that?

I see, Microsoft may benefit from this situation. But if they wrote the driver for HD 4770 have they done similar things for every graphic which was abandoned by the manufacturer? Is it even possible from the programming side?

Honestly I have been thinking about throwing my computer out through the window since about year now. I tried many OSs - Windows 8.1, Windows 10 (at the beginning offered me WDDM driver), Windows Vista (my GPU is 'compatible' with that), Ubuntu 12, Ubuntu 14. None of these OSs worked so well with my GPU. Probably Windows 7 did but I do not remember it now.

So I see how Microsoft benefits from improving number of drivers in Windows Update. However I can not understand how have they have done this. How was it possible?

Comment: They gave you a newer package of Catalyst CC, but the driver it will use for your card will be the same old one as thats the latest one it supports.

Comment: @Linef4ult I did not use CCC. I opened up Device Manager and clicked "Update Driver Software..." on my GPU. The latest driver/CCC version is for XP and is more than year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't write drivers for specific products. They do have drivers for certain generic things, like display drivers to provide a basic level of support that is possible on any graphics card. They don't have time or interest to delve into some manufacturer's specifications (which are not even public) and make a proper performant driver for a specific GPU or other device.

Drivers are built by the hardware manufacturer (of course they can pay someone to do it, but usually not). There are lots of GPUs around, so maybe AMD decided to write the old driver with the new interfaces and that helped? Did you check that the driver actually was updated? Some manufacturers also choose to only distribute drivers through Windows Update for some versions.

And yes, it would be possible for Microsoft to make a driver from the programming side, but only in the sense that it's possible for you or for me. They don't possess any special knowledge about the hardware that is being built by manufacturers, except of course they are constantly talking with nVidia, AMD etc on how to build APIs for graphics to best utilize the hardware and vice versa.

Comment: That is good answer, thanks. However it does not answer why or how I got new driver through Windows Update. On the official site latest driver package is for XP and is more than one year old. Would you like me to do benchmarks with all available official and Windows Update drivers (for my gpu) to compare the scores?

Comment: @FilipHazubski The only thing outsiders can guess is that they maybe just wanted to make a proper driver with the new interfaces. The drivers via Windows Update are as official as any and some manufacturers even distribute drivers only through WinUpdate.

Comment: Please add the information from the comment to the answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @FilipHazubski It kinda is there in the second paragraph, I'll edit